parent component is not updated when invoking in ADDITIONAL child view passed from parent
I have:
export const TagsModal = ({
    visible,
    toggleVisibility,
    tags,
    info,
}) => {
    const [activeTags, setActiveTags] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => console.log(999, activeTags), [activeTags]);

    return <Modal
        visible={visible}
        toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility}
        info={info}
    >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            {tags.map((tag, i) => <Tag
                text={tag}
                key={i}
                onPress={() => {
                    activeTags[tag] = !activeTags[tag];
                    setActiveTags(activeTags);
                }}
            />)}
        </View>
    </Modal>
}

export default TagsModal;

when setActiveTags is called, it does not update parent component (TagsModal) and only when redux state changes the parent component updates.


when setActiveTags is called, it does not update parent component

Because you're not updating state.  You're mutating state.  Specifically here:
activeTags[tag] = !activeTags[tag];

The activeTags object itself is still the same object reference, you've just modified the object.  So when you update state with that object:
setActiveTags(activeTags);

You're updating state with the same object reference.  React sees that it's the same object reference and has no reason to re-render.
Don't mutate state.
Instead, create a new object and update state with that object.  For example:
const newTags = { ...activeTags };
newTags[tag] = !newTags[tag];
setActiveTags(newTags);

Or:
const newTags = { ...activeTags, [tag]: !activeTags[tag] };
setActiveTags(newTags);

